# SPOJ ONEZERO (ones and zeros)

Tags: c++, optimization

I am trying to solve problem [here](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ONEZERO/) by using BFS and storing the remainder and updating it.  However, I get TLE when doing so, how can I eliminate it?

```
int t,n,i,j,z,y;

string l,m;
scanf("%d",&t);
while(t--)
{
    scanf("%d",&n);
    pair<string,int>b;
    queue<pair<string,int> >a;
    b=make_pair("1",1);
    a.push(b);
    bool r[20001]={0};
    while(!a.empty())
    {
        b=a.front();
        a.pop();
       // cout<<b.first<<endl;
        if(b.second%n==0)
        {
            printf("%s\n",b.first.c_str());
            break;
        }
        m=b.first;
        y=b.second;
        z=(y*10)%n;
        if(r[z]==0)
        {    r[z]=1;
             l=m+'0';
        b=make_pair(l,z);
        a.push(b);
        }

        z=(y*10+1)%n;
        if(r[z]==0)
        {    r[z]=1;
             l=m+'1';
        b=make_pair(l,z);
        a.push(b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly explain how your code works?

Comment: Question is to find the smallest number consists of only 0's and 1's  divisible by n. I am using bfs and have a queue consisting of that number as string and remainder in one pair.First I insert 1 and then adding 0 and 1 to the queue if the remainder is 0 then i print the answer and break the loop

Comment: possible duplicate of [SPOJ 370 - Ones and zeros (ONEZERO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945626/spoj-370-ones-and-zeros-onezero)

Comment: You need to invent something more intelligent than BFS. That's the whole point. The problems are designed such that BFS will TLE.

Comment: @n.m. I wouldn't be so sure. It can be a task on graph search optimization.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph Well, you still need to intelligently prune the graph, otherwise where's the challenge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think it another way. You have `a_i = (10^i) % n`, and you would like to find such `b_i = 0..1` that `sum(a_i * b_i, i) % n = 0`. Looks like that's a dynamic programming task.

You have an array `m` where `m[i][j] = true` means "I can represent a number `k` of zeroes and ones such that `k % n == j`, and we need no more than `i` digits for that".

In your DP formula you have `m[i+1][j] = m[i+1][(j + 10^i) % n] = true` when `m[i][j] = true`.

To show that number, you need to backtrack over your `m` from `m[somewhere][0] = true`.

Test your solution for all possible `n` before sending, as they're quite few (only 20000). I think you could even pre-generate all of the solutions and write an array-lookup solution.